# Reading sqlite with pyspark - SQLException: Unsupported type NULL

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read an sqlite db file with Spark and I am getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-b7f53ac120a0> in <module>()
----> 1 sqlContext.read.jdbc(url = jdbcUrl, table='the_table', properties=connectionProperties)

/opt/spark/2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in jdbc(self, url, table, column, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions, predicates, properties)
    557             gateway = self._spark._sc._gateway
    558             jpredicates = utils.toJArray(gateway, gateway.jvm.java.lang.String, predicates)
--> 559             return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jpredicates, jprop))
    560         return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jprop))
    561 

/opt/spark/2.4.4/python/lib/py4j-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/spark/2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/spark/2.4.4/python/lib/py4j-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1744.jdbc.
: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type NULL
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$8.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:316)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getSchema(JdbcUtils.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.apply(JDBCRelation.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I believe the issue is `: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type NULL` so the data I am reading has null and that is not supported, or something - but the issue is the data has zero nulls and it still won't read the table.

Here's my code:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedb/test.db"
connectionProperties = {
    "user" : "",
    "password" : "",
  "driver" : "org.sqlite.JDBC"
}

sqlContext.read.jdbc(url = jdbcUrl, table='the_table', properties=connectionProperties)
```

Running that I get the error show above.

I have also tried

```
sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedb/test.db',
                                       dbtable = 'the_table', 
                                       driver = 'org.sqlite.JDBC')
```

And I also get the same error message.

I'm obviously missing something here, and all the threads I can find are either java or scala, and whilst I've tried various other things suggested in those, it just doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you share your table's DDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to import data from SQLite table using spark. Actually, in spark, JDBCDialect for `SQLite` is not present. Due to this, SQLite types are not getting matched as expected and hence this exception.

To fix that, you need to write the jdbc dialect by extending Spark abstract `JdbcDialect` class as below-

```
object SQLiteDialect extends JdbcDialect {
...
}
```

Here you can take help from other available dialects like [PostgressDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/PostgresDialect.scala)

Now to test follow steps mentioned below -

1. package the `SQLiteDialect` compiled class plus companion object into a JAR
2. Copy JAR to jars folder in Spark binary installation (optional, probably can set path in an extra --jars argument instead)

Then run the following test in spark-shell after creating SQLite table and sample data:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect(org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.SQLiteDialect)

val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedb/test.db',
                                       dbtable = 'the_table', 
                                       driver = 'org.sqlite.JDBC').load()

jdbcDF.show()

JdbcDialects.unregisterDialect(org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.SQLiteDialect)
```

ref- [this thread](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/I-would-like-to-add-JDBCDialect-to-support-Vertica-database-tp28507p28520.html)

**It seems there is a [medium blog](https://medium.com/@huaxing/customize-spark-jdbc-data-source-to-work-with-your-dedicated-database-dialect-beec6519af27) available which talks about `SQLite` dialect and have good explanation available, please refer.**

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers are not directly usable, the following in an adaption of the answer by Som that can be directly run:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcType
import java.sql.Types
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{JdbcDialect, JdbcDialects}
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new JdbcDialect() {
override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.toLowerCase.startsWith("jdbc:sqlite")
override def getCatalystType(
          sqlType: Int,
          typeName: String,
          size: Int,
          md: MetadataBuilder): Option[DataType] = sqlType match {
  case Types.NULL =>
    typeName match {
      case "BIT" => Option(BooleanType)
      case "BYTE" => Option(IntegerType)
      case "BLOB" => Option(ByteType)
      case "STRING" => Option(StringType)
      case _ => None
    }
  case _ => None
}
override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match 
{
  case ShortType => Option(JdbcType("SMALLINT", Types.SMALLINT))
  case _ => None
}
})
```

This defines the custom requirements as per the linked medium blog from the answer from Som with two extra cases (BLOB and STRING) and registers it for use.

NOTE: In my case this was to load an SQLITE file from a databricks notebook environment and the above needed to be run in scala cell. Then loads (via python or SQL cells) worked.